# getText() on a TextView returns an empty string

Tags: android, textview, listener, listadapter

I'll start showing you the code.

```
lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

//Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
 ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
          this, locationsList,
          R.layout.list_results, new String[]{
          TAG_NATION, TAG_CITY, TAG_NAME, TAG_TYPE, TAG_PRICERANGE, TAG_ID, TAG_IMAGE},
          new int[]{R.id.tvResNation, R.id.tvResCity, R.id.tvResName, R.id.tvResType, R.id.tvResPrice, R.id.tvResID,
                        R.id.ivResImage1});


lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Intent in = new Intent(ResultsActivity.this, LocationActivity.class);
                String resID = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvResID)).getText().toString();
                String resName = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvResName)).getText().toString();
                String resNation = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvResNation)).getText().toString();
                String resCity = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvResCity)).getText().toString();
                String resType = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvResType)).getText().toString();
                in.putExtra(TAG_ID, resID);
                in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, resName);
                in.putExtra(TAG_TYPE, resType);
                in.putExtra(TAG_NATION, resNation);
                in.putExtra(TAG_CITY, resCity);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });
```

All the properties that we set on the adapter are retrieved by a JSONObject that we convert to an hashmap (we have verified that all the properties have the right value).

Once the properties are set (?) on the adapter using that hashmap the property `resID` apparently is not. From the `textView` with id `R.id.tvResID` we always receive an empty string using `getText()`.

The funny thing is that all the properties have a value before the setting of the adapter and all the other properties, except ID, are retrieved inside the listener...

Here's the XML for the adapter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.66">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tvResNation"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tvResCity"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tvResName"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tvResType"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tvResPrice"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ivResImage1"
        android:layout_weight="0.33" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvResID"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**SOLVED**
We set the adapter in another part of the code and there was a field missing...

Comment: This should be better

Comment: `String resID` replace instead  of `TextView resID`

Comment: It's `tvResID` not `resID` like the string

Comment: look your xml or code may be this id used somewhere

Comment: edited. Everything seems good to me...

Comment: We assured that the problem is the adapter. Setting the text in the xml proves that

Answer (score 0):

You can try like ,

```
TextView txtView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvResID);
String str = txtView.getText().toString();
Log.i("TAG", "Text is : " + str);
```

This should work.

**EDIT 1**

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvResID"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="hello world!!!"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>
```

After this you will get

> hello world!!!

Comment: check tvResID contains any string or empty TextView?

Comment: find what is text on tvResID?

Comment: Yes exactly. The problem is the adapter

Comment: As you can see, we used SimpleAdapter

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
String text = (String) mListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
```